# Extra Scroll Bar when using css scroll snap

Tags: html, css

I have a website that I am building for school and I wanted to spice it up a little! So I added a effect where objects stack on top of each other.

The problem arises when I try to make the website auto snap to get the sections to stop. [image: Problem 1]

[image: Problem 2]

How do I make the scroll bar dissapear? The effect is fine as long as I have this code disabled.

```
overflow-y: scroll;
scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
max-height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
```

Has anyone run into this before?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Comment: No that's not what I am going for, in the case of the effect I am trying to replicate, [Here](https://vinceumo.github.io/devNotes/CSS/slide-stacking-effect-using-position-sticky/#basic-effect-with-position-sticky) all I want is for the content to be forced to snap! So you can't scroll in-between content/halfway through.